# Use of "not even once" instead of never

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

In the following sentence can "never" be replaced with "not even once"

> I had never embroidered such a pattern in the class.

> I had not embroidered such a pattern even once in the class.

Actually I have used the word "never" many times already. I searched Internet and found many phrases but "not once" seemed suitable to me.

Comment: You say you've used the word "never" many times already. But if that's the right word for the context, just *keep using it*. Randomly switching to different words with the same or similar meanings isn't a mark of good writing, even with people who have a wide enough vocabulary that they can do this everywhere without asking for help or leafing through dictionaries. Note that it's perfectly idiomatic to say *I've never once done that*, or *I've never done that even once* if you want to be more emphatic. Or *I've **never ever** done it* to be even *more* emphatic.

Comment: Your usage of *not even once* is a bit clumsy.  I would rather read the word *never* again.  *This would be the first time....* is a another way of saying *never before*.  *Annie had never ridden a bike before [today].*  *Today would be Annie's first time riding a bike.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, "never" = "not even once".

"not even once" is just a way of adding emphasis.

And, because it is used for emphasis, the phrase "not even once" should not be split.

Example:  "I did not even once embroider such a pattern in class."

Occasionally, for even more emphasis, you will hear "I never did [action].  Not even once."

Example:  "I never [embroidered such a pattern in class]. Not even once."

Comment: Close. "Never" = "not once". "**Even**" adds emphasis without changing the meaning